# Appending a data type to a json file

Tags: python, json, excel, pandas

I want to append a column name with the value of it's data type to a JSON file. I can't seem to figure out how to get the data type of the value based on the name. Not sure how to append this correctly in the for-loop for data['type'].

**Excel Spreadsheet**

[image]

**Code**

```
import xlrd 
from collections import OrderedDict
import json
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('./file1.xlsx')
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
```

```
data_list = []
data = OrderedDict()

for colnum in range(0, sh.ncols):
    data['name'] = sh.row_values(0)[colnum]
    data['description'] = sh.row_values(1)[colnum]
    data_list.append(data.copy())
    
data_list = {'columns': data_list}
j = json.dumps(data_list)
with open('seq1.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(j)
```

**Output**

```
{
  "columns": [
    {
      "name": "FILEID",
      "description": "FILEID"
    },
    {
      "name": "FILETYPE",
      "description": "FILETYPE"
    },
}
```

**Expected output**

```
{
  "columns": [
    {
      "name": "fileid",
      "description": "FILEID",
      "type": "keyword"

    },
    {
      "name": "filetype",
      "description": "FILETYPE",
      "type": "keyword"
    },
}
```

Comment: There is nowhere in your code that you add a value for a keyword "type".  How are you expecting to get the output you say you want?

Comment: I tried assigning a value to data['type'] however it is not netting me the results I am looking for. My question is what is the correct way of assigning it in order to get me the data type?

Comment: Give us your actual failing attempt.  Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.